# Disable Journaling of Hfsplus Partition in Systems other than OSX?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, hfs+

Is it possible to disable hfsplus journaling for hfsplus partitions in systems other than using OSX's `diskutil`?

My goal is to mount that partition writeable under ubuntu..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have a partition which is readable and writeable by Ubuntu and OS X, preferably an HFS+ partition.  Do you care which OS creates it, or did you specifically want to avoid creating it with OS X?

Comment: I'm trying to access an existing hfs+ partition

Comment: but it was created by mac os x

Answer (score 2):

It seems the only 100% reliable way is to disable journalling in OSX, hfsplus-tools doesn't have the ability to disable it without reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
mount -t hfsplus <device path here>
```

[Ripped off from: LQ.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mounting-hfs-volumes-under-linux-521189/) <- Thread might help you a bit more.

And here's [an HFS+ driver you could try.](http://www.ardistech.com/hfsplus/) Looks like it's read only.

Comment: OP asked for writeable, HFS+ with Journaling is read-only at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to be that there are tools only in Windows 7 to write into both ext2-3-4 and hfs+, while Linux can write into  tfs, read hfs+, mac os x can read ext2-3-4, ntfs but cannot write into them.

Answer (score 0):

This utility works great from Windows 7 64 bit to write into ext2-3-4
Ext2Fsd-0.50.exe
while 
MacDrive_7.0.1 with updates such as [all together]
MacDrive_7.1.0 and
MacDrive_7.2.2 and
MacDrive_7.2.4 and
MacDrive_7.2.5
work great from windows 7 64 bit to write into HFS+ journaled even case sensitive volumes.
Thus a option to have the third OS on your machine.

Comment: This seems more like a comment on how to avoid ubuntu as opposed to pointing to technical details how to enable writing to HFS+J volumes.